# Dependency inject object created form parameterized constructor in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a generic Http Client contract as below

```
public interface IHttpClient
    {
        public Task<T> GetData<T>(string url);
        public Task<T> PutData<T>(T data);
        public Task<T> PostData<T>(T data);
    }
```

This contract is implemented by a class with 3 constructors as follows. Not showing implementations except for brevity.

```
public class HttpRestClient : IHttpClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public HttpRestClient()
        {
            this._httpClient = new HttpClient();
        }
        public HttpRestClient(string url)
        {
            this._httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        }

        public HttpRestClient(string certName, HttpClientHandler handler)
        {
            var cert = GetMyCert(certName);
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            this._httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }

        public Task<T> GetData<T>(string url) ...

        public Task<T> PostData<T>(T data) ...

        public Task<T> PutData<T>(T data) ...
    }
```

This is registered as `builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpClient, HttpRestClient>();` in program.cs

currently, HttpRestClient class is being used as default constructor object by many other clients in the application. Now I am trying to use the httpClient object thats created from `public HttpRestClient(string certName, HttpClientHandler handler)` constructor in my client.
I am trying something like this.

```
 public class MyClient : IMyClient
    {
        private readonly IAddressService addressService;
        private readonly ILocationService locationService;
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly IHttpClient httpclient;
        public MyClient(IAddressService addressService,
            ILocationService locationService,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            this.addressService = addressService;
            this.locationService = locationService;
            this.logger = logger;
            httpclient = new HttpRestClient("MyCertName", new HttpClientHandler());
        }

        public Task<string> SendAsync(string url)
        {
            //Some Validation Logic
            var data = this.httpclient.GetData(url);
            //do some modififcation
            this.httpclient.PostData<string>(url);
        }
```

But this is making it difficult to Unit test my method as I am creating a new HttpRestClient object using my needed ctor in the constructor. I know I should have to pass in IhttpClient interface type and assign it to my private member `httpclient` which I use in `MyClient` class.
But, how would I instruct the runtime to pass in the object thats from HttpClient cert constructor to be passed in while other classes using httpclient still get their default HttpClient versions?
Do I need to change my registration in program.cs? How would I achieve this and yet Unit test my code?

Comment: ...why aren't you using `IHttpClientFactory` like you're meant to?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: But then I still need to reimplement all methods in RestClient. All I need is to have same business Logic as of httpRestClient but a different configuration of my httpClient with a certificate.

Comment: Yeah, to provide a generic wrapper by for the CRUD operations, to help customize outgoing httprequests and incoming httpresponses. This code was written probably a year ago by a junior dev. when I am reading this I feel Ihttpclientfactory may be used to customize and achieve what this class is doing but it would be a much involved refactor i feel

Comment: Yeah - switching to `IHttpClientFactory` won't be trivial - but it will be worth it in the end.

Comment: Any time anyone says "generic wrapper" I wince. Or even just hearing the word "wrapper" makes my skin crawl: chocolate bars have wrappers, not software. I like to think we've evolved past GoF design-patterns by now.

Comment: I understand you..for sure will look into switching to ihhtpclientfactory...learnt something new. :) thank you @Dai

Comment: If you decided to go for `IHttpClientFactory` you might want to close the question. In general, DI containers work best if there is a single class or instance registered for a given interface. Some containers support named registrations and/or sub-containers that could be used for disambiguation, but this tend to lead to added complexity, and is best avoided if you can.